# OnMessage event doesn't fire in Telegram.Bot package

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Hi experts :) I'm trying to show a MessageBox whenever my telegram bot receives a message . I have used Telegram.Bot package and written these codes :

```
       TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("MyToken");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
        Bot.OnUpdate += Bot_OnUpdate;

    }

    private void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.Text);
    }

    private void Bot_OnUpdate(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.UpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        var botClient = (TelegramBotClient)sender;
        MessageBox.Show(e.Update.Message.Text);
    }
```

but it doesn't show messagebox when I send a message to my bot .
What's the matter ? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line of code added and it works :) :

```
 TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("MyToken");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bot.StartReceiving();
        Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
    }

    private void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, Telegram.Bot.Args.MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.Text);
    }
```

`Bot.StartReceiving()` was the thing that was needed to start listening for new messages :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check out if all referenced libraries are build on x64 or AnyCPU

I had a x86 project in my solution and therefore the OnMessage was not firing.